# Why curl returns "userName%" by GeoServer REST API create new user

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, curl

When I insert this below link like GeoServer 2.17.1 RESTful API I got only: `userName%`

```
curl -u admin:@dmin9901 -X POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/ -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"userName\": \"test\",  \"password\": \"test1234\",  \"enabled\": true}"
```

It can't create new user in my GeoServer, it would be bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API docs it looks like the API endpoint you are hitting is incorrect.

[GeoServer API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/usergroup.yaml)

Based on this I would expect the call to be:

```
curl -u admin:@dmin9901 -X POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/usergroup/users/ -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"userName\": \"test\",  \"password\": \"test1234\",  \"enabled\": true}"
```

If that is not the issue I'd look in the geoserver log file (by default it will be in `$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/logs`. As well as adding the `-v` option to the `curl` command to see what the response headers look like.